# No me da resultado en html

Tags: javascript, html

quisiera saber si alguno tiene idea de por que el siguiente codigo no me da,

```js
var numero = document.getElementById('numero');

function calcular() {
 
  var TuFecha = new Date('01/01/2018');
 
  var dias = parseInt(numero.value);
  TuFecha.setDate(TuFecha.getDate() + dias);
  resultado.innerText = TuFecha.getDate() + '/' +
    (TuFecha.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + TuFecha.getFullYear();
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" id="numero"/>
  <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
</p>
<p>Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span></p>
```

La verdad no se cual sea el error, al momento de probar en el navegador google no me da ningun resultado, lo mismo pasa en firefox .Intente cambiando algunas cosas pero no me sigue dando, gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún error en la consola? `CTRL + SHIFT + I`

Comment: Revise y me sale esto :

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at calcular (?nombre=hola&apellidos=&numtelefono=:72)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (?nombre=hola&apellidos=&numtelefono=:85)
calcular @ ?nombre=hola&apellidos=&numtelefono=:72
onclick @ ?nombre=hola&apellidos=&numtelefono=:85

Comment: Bienvenido. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deberían incluir una breve descripción de lo que debería hacer el código, entre otras cosas. Más detalles en [ask] y [mcve].

Comment: Esta bien, lo tomare en cuenta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El codigo aparentemente esta bien hecho, probablemente el problema debe estar en la posicion en la que colocas el codigo javascript, por lo que comentas posiblemente estes tratando de obtener document.getElementById('numero'); antes de que el input exista en el DOM. por eso cuando la funcion calcular es ejecutada te dice que no puede obtener la propiedad 'value' de una variable que es 'null'.

Comment: Gracias, tratare de colocar el script despues del <p></p>, y verificare, ....

Answer (score 0):

Comparto una estructura similar:

```
 var numero = document.getElementById('numero');
 function calcular() {
 //la fecha
 var TuFecha = new Date('01/01/2018');
 //dias a sumar
 var dias = parseInt(numero.value);
//nueva fecha sumada
TuFecha.setDate(TuFecha.getDate() + dias);
//formato de salida para la fecha
resultado.innerText = TuFecha.getDate() + '/' +
 (TuFecha.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + TuFecha.getFullYear();
}


<p>
<input type="text" id="numero"/>
<button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
</p>
<p>Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span></p>
```

Comment: Gracias, intentare...